# Creating a hashmap using perl split function

Tags: perl, io, hashmap

I am attempting to create a hashmap from a text file. The way the text file is set up is as follows.

```
(integer)<-- varying white space --> (string value) 
    .                .                      .
    .                .                      .
    .                .                      . 
(integer)<-- varying white space --> (string value)
```

eg:

```
   5           this is a test
  23        this is another test
 123         this is the final test
```

What I want to do is assign the key to the integer, and then the entire string following to the value. I was trying something along the lines of

```
%myHashMap;

while(my $info = <$fh>){
    chomp($info);
    my ($int, $string) = split/ /,$info;
    $myHashMap{$int} = $string;
}
```

This doesn't work though because I have spaces in the string. Is there a way to clear the initial white space, grab the integer, assign it to $int, then clear white space till you get to the string, then take the remainder of the text on that line and place it in my $string value?

Answer (score 3):

You could replace

```
split / /, $info      # Fields are separated by a space.
```

with

```
split / +/, $info     # Fields are separated by spaces.
```

or the more general

```
split /\s+/, $info    # Fields are separated by whitespace.
```

but you'd still face with the problem of the leading spaces. To ignore those, use

```
split ' ', $info
```

This special case splits on whitespace, ignoring leading whitespace.

Don't forget to tell Perl that you expect at most two fields!

```
$ perl -E'say "[$_]" for split(" ", "  1   abc def ghi", 2)'
[1]
[abc def ghi]
```

The other option would be to use the following:

```
$info =~ /^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S.*)/
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to split each line of text on whitespace into two fields

This example program assumes that the input file is passed as a parameter on the command line. I have used `Data::Dump` only to show the resulting hash structure

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %data;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s/\s*\z//;
    my ($key, $val) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    next unless defined $val;  # Ensure that there were two fields
    $data{$key} = $val;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%data;
```

#### output

```
{
  5   => "this is a test",
  23  => "this is another test",
  123 => "this is the final test",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you clear initial white space use this

```
$info =~ s/^\s+//g;
```

second you have more than 2 spaces in between integer and string so use split like this to give 2 space with plus

```
split/  +/,$info;
```

The code is

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %myHashMap;

while(my $info = <$fh>){
    chomp($info);
    $info =~ s/^\s+//g;
    my ($int, $string) = split/  +/,$info;
    $myHashMap{$int} = $string;
}
```